# Setting div class width to the widest div is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, width

I have a list of elements that content is generated with php from a database (I can multiply their values). I want them to have the width of the widest element - it should be updated on page load and click on select tag (multiplying the values). The script works on page load, but it's not updating the width when I'm clicking the select tag. Also, when the widest element shrinks, the width is not shrinking as it should, but staying the same as before.

```
<head>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<select class="multiply_ing">
    <option value="0.5">0.5x</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1x</option>
    <option value="5">5x</option>
    <option value="10">10x</option>
</select>

// it looks like this - data-val generated from php <p class='ing_wght' data-val='$ing_weight'></p>
<p class='ing_wght' data-val='33'></p>
<p class='ing_wght' data-val='54'></p>
<p class='ing_wght' data-val='7312'></p>
<p class='ing_wght' data-val='6'></p>
```

```
// js/jquery code for multiplying is in the same file (above this one) as the script to change the width

$(".multiply_ing").on("click", function(){
    ingWidth();
});
$(window).on("load", function(){
    ingWidth();
});

function ingWidth(){
    let maxWidth = 0;
    let widestIngWght = null;
    let ingWght;
    
    $(".ing_wght").each(function(){
       ingWght = $(this);
       if(ingWght.width() > maxWidth){
            maxWidth = ingWght.width();
            widestIngWght = ingWght; 
       }
    });

    $(".ing_wght").css("width", maxWidth);
    console.log(maxWidth);
}
```

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: When I run your code all the p tags get the same width

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem. When I'm shrinking the content it stays the same (so it's too wide) and I can't update it on select tag click

Comment: So you mean, when you change the select, the p width don't change?. Have you tried inspecting the p. They will by default have the width of the container they are in.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It looks like the width can be changed only once after page refresh, that's why I couldn't change it with select tag, because window onload did it already. Unfortunately, even if I delete window onload, I can still change the width only 1 time. After that, the width won't change no matter what (only after the page is refreshed).

Comment: I'm surprised JQuery is still being used these days, is ancient.

Comment: @Bargros Not everyone wants to learn 13 new JS frameworks every week just to make a small, private project.

Comment: @Astw41 The fact you see everything as a framework tells me you don't know much about whats out there. Sounds like you're repeating what others have told you.

Comment: @Bargros How do I see everything as a framework? There are just too many of them. It's just a private project, I'm not going to learn whole 3 libraries, 2 frameworks and more languages just so I can finish it. I'm trying to utilize the knowledge that I already have (and possibly expand it). Please, respond to the problems in the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. I had to add an if statement that removes the width from the class `$(this)` if it's wider or equal to previously defined max width.

```
$(".multiply_ing").on("click", function(){
    ingWidth();
});

$(window).on("load", function(){
    ingWidth();
});

function ingWidth(){
    let maxWidth = 0;
    let widestIngWght = null;
    let ingWght;
    
    $(".ing_wght").each(function(){
        
        ingWght = $(this);
        
        if(ingWght.width() >= maxWidth){
            ingWght.width("");
        }

        if(ingWght.width() > maxWidth){
            maxWidth = ingWght.width();
            widestIngWght = ingWght; 
        }
    });

    $(".ing_wght").css("width", maxWidth);
}
```

Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(".multiply_ing").on("click", function(){
    ingWidth();
});
```

To:

```
$(document).on("change", ".multiply_ing", function(){
    ingWidth();
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :/